# How to find files except given name?

Tags: linux, bash, find

There is a directory containing the following files:

```
.
├── bla-bla-bla1.tar.7z
├── bla-bla-bla2.tar.7z
├── bla-bla-bla3.tar.7z
└── _bla-bla-bla_foo.tar.7z
```

I need to **find** and **delete** all of the files that in the format of `*.7z` except `_*.7z`

I've tried:

```sh
find /backups/ -name "*.7z" -type f -mtime +180 -delete
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 31):

Another approach is to use an additional, negated primary with `find`:

```
 find /backups/ -name "*.7z"  ! -name '_*.7z' -type f -mtime +180 -delete
```

The simple regex in the other answers is better for your use case, but this demonstrates a more general approach using the `!` operator available to `find`.

Comment: Actually the second "name" should be `'_*.7z'`, which will exclude the 7z files starting with `"_"`, in the current form will exclude only a file named (exactly) `"_.7z"`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I think that's just a long-overlooked typo.

Answer (score 11):

In regular expressions, the `^` operator means "any character except for". Thus `[^_]` means "any character except for _". E.g.:

```
"[^_]*.7z"
```

So, if your intention is to exclude files *starting* with `_`, your full command line would be:

```
find /backups/ -name "[^_]*.7z" -type f -mtime +180 -delete
```

If you'd like to exclude *any* occerance of `_`, you can use the `and` and `not` operators of `find`, like:

```
find . -name "*.7z" -and -not -name "*_*"
```

Comment: Thanks for this "[^_]*.7z" its very easy :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 find . -name "*[^_].7z"
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way given you have bash 4.2.25, is to simply use bash pattern matching to remove all .7z, but the ones having _.7z, like this:

```
touch a.7z b.7z c.7z d_.7z e_.7z f.txt
rm *[^_].7z
```