# How to remove all folders except a few mentioned one in linux

Tags: linux, unix, rm

I have the following folder structure inside my `wp-content` folder =>

```
2016/ => it has many subfolders in it and I wanna keep them
2015/ => it has many subfolders in it and I wanna keep them
2014/ => it has many subfolders in it and I wanna keep them
2013/ => it has many subfolders in it and I wanna keep them

besides those folder there are tons of temp folders which I want to delete along with anything inside it. The folder name look like this:

ZhsvhgTjh/
Vgfsugu79/
1agDjgdki/
8gdygREfh/
Hbjddsyug/
....so on....
```

Now the problem is if I run `rm -f` then it is gonna remove everything inside that folder, including the folders like `2016, 2015, 2014, 2013`.

Also if I try the following: `find . -name a -exec rm -rf {} \;` then it will only work for 1 folder name and I have type each random folder name which is insane as it has almmost 20,000+ temp folders.

So, I was hoping if anyone can help me with a command using which I can remove all the folders and contents within it except the `2016, 2015, 2014, 2013` folders and their contents.

Also as this a remove command can anyone let me know if there is a way I can run a count command to see if the query is selecting the right number of folders or not? I don't wanna delete any important stuffs accidentally.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find files except given name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020759/how-to-find-files-except-given-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print tree

```
prodrive11@raccoon:~/tmpp/wp-content$ ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
   .
   |-2015
   |---keep2
   |---keep3
   |-2016
   |---keep1
   |---keep2
   |-NKAXOIND
   |-x232sfsw
   |---we233ds
```

Show garbage folders:

```
   prodrive11@raccoon:~/tmpp/wp-content$ find . -type d | grep -Pv '20\d{2}' | tail -n +2                   ./x232sfsw
    ./x232sfsw/we233ds
    ./NKAXOIND
```

Count them

```
prodrive11@raccoon:~/tmpp/wp-content$ find . -type d | grep -Pv '20\d{2}' | tail -n +2 | wc -l
3
```

Remove them

```
prodrive11@raccoon:~/tmpp/wp-content$ find . -type d | grep -Pv '20\d{2}' | tail -n +2 | xargs rm -rf
```

Show tree again

```
prodrive11@raccoon:~/tmpp/wp-content$ ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
   .
   |-2015
   |---keep2
   |---keep3
   |-2016
   |---keep1
   |---keep2
```

Comment: Hi, I have a question. If I wanna exclude more folders like lets say ai wanna exclude these following folders and all contents within it: `2016/
2015/,
2014/,
nginx-helper/,
wpseo-redirects/,
gravity_forms/` how can I edit the above command to fit my need? As I can see you are only excluding folders that starts with `20`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just add more regex to grep, first one 20\d{2} matches all years 1st century of 2000-2099

  `find . -type d  | grep -Pv '(20\d{2}|nginx|wpseo)' | tail -n +2`